# I have problems running "helm install --name bluecompute ibmcase/bluecompute-ce" when trying to complete the IBM course

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to follow this guide https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/microservices-app-on-kubernetes?task=1 but in the Task 4, step 7 I get a problem like this:

[image]

I dont cant find solution to this problem, and I dont know exaclty what is happening and why the problem is ocurring. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have not initialized helm with a service account.

In rbac-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

**Step 1**: `kubectl apply -f rbac-config.yaml`

**Step 2**: `helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200`

**Step 3**: Test the setup with `heml ls`. There would not be any output from running this command and that is expected. Now, you can run `helm install --name bluecompute ibmcase/bluecompute-ce`

This is documented for setting up helm on IBM Cloud here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-helm#helm